# Why are LSP violations in PHP sometimes fatal, and sometimes warnings?

Tags: php, liskov-substitution-principle

This LSP violation [raises a Fatal Error](https://3v4l.org/vMJW5):

```
abstract class AbstractService { }
abstract class AbstractFactory { abstract function make(AbstractService $s); }
class ConcreteService extends AbstractService { }
class ConcreteFactory extends AbstractFactory { function make(ConcreteService $s) {} }
```

This LSP violation [also raises a Fatal Error](https://3v4l.org/D0kQ3):

```
interface AbstractService { }
interface AbstractFactory { function make(AbstractService $s); }
class ConcreteService implements AbstractService { }
class ConcreteFactory implements AbstractFactory { function make(ConcreteService $s) {} }
```

While this LSP violation only [raises a Warning](https://3v4l.org/k5II8):

```
class Service { }
class Factory { function make(Service $s) {} }
class MyService extends Service { }
class MyFactory extends Factory { function make(MyService $s) {} }
```

Why? Shouldn't they all be fatal since they're all contravariant?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first case, it is a fatal error because [PHP requires you to be compatible with a parent *abstract* class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php):

> When inheriting from an abstract class... signatures of the methods must match.

The [same is true](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) in the second case:

> The class implementing the interface must use the exact same method signatures as are defined in the interface. Not doing so will result in a fatal error.

In the third case, you extend a normal PHP class, not abstract. PHP allows you to change the signature, albeit with a warning.

It obviously isn't a good practice, and does violate LSP as you point out. Just one of the many ways PHP gives you sharp objects, and lets you hurt yourself if you aren't careful. =)

If you want LSP enforced, you need to use an interface, abstract, or make your method `final` in the parent class.

Here's an example of `final`: https://3v4l.org/s42XG

Comment: I follow the mechanics, but I don't understand the rationale. Zeev added the restriction in 5.0.0-rc2 according to the [Changelog](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php), but it's not clear to me if that was for LSP or another reason and if polymorphic is-a relations were skipped for BC with PHP 4 classes.

Comment: "PHP gives you sharp objects, and lets you hurt yourself if you aren't careful". So true. I suppose the rationale is lost in the mists of time.

Comment: The [lsp_errors RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/lsp_errors), targeting PHP 8, is now under discussion to address this inconsistency.

Answer (score 1):

In May 2019, the [LSP errors RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/lsp_errors) updated the language. As of PHP 8, the engine will *always* generate a *fatal error* for incompatible method signatures.

Before this change, a derived class could change a signature willy-nilly, ignore the error, and move on. No more: classes, just like `abstract class` and `interface` must abide by LSP.