# "Declaration should be compatible with" when extending PHP native class (possible bug, possible misunderstanding)

Tags: php, datetime

**Summary**

The following code is generating:

PHP 5.6: `DEBUG Declaration of MyDateTime::add() should be compatible with DateTimeImmutable::add($interval) on line number 12`

PHP 7.0: `WARNING Declaration of MyDateTime::add(DateInterval $interval) should be compatible with DateTimeImmutable::add($interval) on line number 12`

(environments from http://phptester.net/)

```
<?php

class MyDateTime extends \DateTimeImmutable
{
    /**
     * @param DateInterval $interval
     */
    public function add(DateInterval $interval)
    {
        return parent::add($interval);
    }
}

$dt = new MyDateTime();
echo "{$dt->format('Y-m-d')}\n";
$dt2 = $dt->add(new DateInterval('P7D'));
echo "{$dt2->format('Y-m-d')}\n";
```

**Reason**

I have extended `\DateTimeImmutable` to add in a few helper methods. When implementing the `add()` method, I used PhpStorm's Override Method feature, which gave me

```
/**
 * @param DateInterval $interval
 */
public function add(DateInterval $interval)
{
    parent::add($interval);
}
```

(I added the `return` for expected immutability behaviour)

All documentation points to `add()` requiring an instance of `DateInterval`. When I remove it from the method signature, it works without a warning.

**Question**

Am I missing something here (possibly Liskov related)? Or could this be a bug in the PHP core? I could understand if I had a completely different method signature, but I'm recreating it exactly as the documentation.

Comment: Are you using namespaces? If yes, try: `public function add(\DateInterval $interval)`. Still weird that it works if you remove the code hinting, since it clearly states that it should be a DateInterval object in the manual.

Comment: Have you tried using: `DateTimeImmutable::add()` rather than `parent:add()`? I know it seems far-fetched, but sometimes these things surprise you.

Comment: In the real code it's fully namespaced. This is a stripped down version to just the code that throws the warning.

Comment: @Martin Odd; I just ran it on 5.5.9 and 7.0.8 and got the described warnings. (To get the DEBUG message on 5.5.9 I had to make sure to run with `E_ALL`.)

Comment: @MattGibson yes, odd.

Comment: I did find a useful [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897795/is-there-a-way-to-redefine-a-type-hint-to-a-descendant-class-when-extending-an-a) which points that as you can't *change* type declarations in child classes, it's better to use interfaces for this purpose, rather than extensions of parents.

Comment: Also, Running the code you provided on another online PHP tester ([PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/)) resulted in a `Strict Standards` error, which is worded differently from the errors you mention from the other online PHP tool, above.