# How to have type hinting that work with class inheritance in PHP

Tags: php, inheritance, interface, abstract-class, type-hinting

Lets say we have the following classes:

```
<?php
abstract class AnimalTrainer
{
    abstract function train(Animal $animal);
}

class DogTrainer extends AnimalTrainer implements DogTrainerInterface
{
    public function train(Animal $animal)
    {
        // code goes here
    }
}

interface DogTrainerInterface
{
    public function train(Dog $animal)
}

# ==== Animal & Dog ====
class Animal
{
}

class Dog extends Animal
{
}
```

All animal trainers can train animals, but Dog trainers can only train dogs. So the Interface for DogTrainer should state that. But that goes against the abstract declaration in AnimalTrainer since states the train method requires an Animal.

Is there a way in PHP to make DogTrainers work with both the abstract class and the interface?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897795/is-there-a-way-to-redefine-a-type-hint-to-a-descendant-class-when-extending-an-a

Comment: Thanks for the link!. It was really helpful

Comment: This also might come in handy regarding this question. http://software-engineer.gatsbylee.com/abstract-method-implementation-in-php-is-different-from-in-java/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to redefine a type hint to a descendant class when extending an abstract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897795/is-there-a-way-to-redefine-a-type-hint-to-a-descendant-class-when-extending-an-a)