# Type Hinting arguments does not work as expected

Tags: php, laravel

I have a situation when I type hint the arguments, it does not work properly.

I have a `BaseTransformer` check the type hinting

```
abstract class BaseTransformer
{
   ...

    public function transform(Model $modelOrCollection);
}
```

Then I have a `UserTransformer` check the type hinting

```
class UserTransformer extends BaseTransformer
{
    .....
    .....
    public function transform(User $user)
    {
        return [
            ....
            ....
        ];
    }
}
```

but when I new up the `UserTransformer` it throws an exception which says the type do not match

> ErrorException with message 'Declaration of
>   App\Transformers\UserTransformer::transform(App\Transformers\User
>   $user) should be compatible with
>   App\Transformers\BaseTransformer::transform(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
>   $modelOrCollection)'

As per my knowledge the App\User class extends the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` and when I am using the `instanceof` operator it returns true.

```
>>> App\User::find(20333) instanceof Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model 
=> true
```

What is going wrong ?

I am using `Laravel 5.6`, `php7.2`

Comment: And possibly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897795/is-there-a-way-to-redefine-a-type-hint-to-a-descendant-class-when-extending-an-a

Answer (score 1):

In UserTransformer , you can't write `public function transform(User $user)`, you must stick to the parent class declaration `public function transform(Model $modelOrCollection)`

Comment: I think OP knows that, but is more asking _why_ since User extends Model, and OP wants to be more specific in the hinting as to _which_ model can be accepted.

Comment: yes. my question was why is it not working. if i change the type to Model in the UserTransformerobviously it works