# How to support IDE language server type hints for methods that return $this in PHP

Tags: php, php-language-server

I want to ship a class `A` that can be locally extended (`LocalA`). Most methods need to return `$this` so that calls can be chained. I'm looking for a way to type-hint the return values of the methods defined in `A` (and `LocalA`) to say "it returns the same class as the object upon which the method was called".

This way IDEs can offer up suggested methods following a call.

`:self` is a language possibility but it won’t do. It would mean that after a method defined in `A`, the IDE would see the result as being an `A` and not a `LocalA`:

```php
<?php
class A {
  function a():self {
    return $this;
  }
}
class B extends A {
  function b():self {
    return $this;
  }
}

$o = new B();
$o->➊
$o->a()->➋
```

At ➊ the IDE will list possible methods `a()` and `b()`, but at ➋ it will only list `a()`.

`:static` would be nice, but is invalid, not supported/implemented in PHP.

The following looked promising as an answer, and PHP is happy with running it:

```
trait trait1 {
  function a():self {
    return $this;
  }
}
trait trait2 {
  function b():self {
    return $this;
  }
}

class A {
  use trait1;
}
class B {
  use trait1;
  use trait2;
}

$o = new B();
$o->➊ // offers a() and b() ✔
$o->a()->➋ // offers only a() ✖ treats the trait's 'self' as that trait, I think.
```

...but annoyingly my language server (intellephense via [coc-phpls](https://github.com/marlonfan/coc-phpls/)) doesn't realise that 'self' from a trait should refer to `B` and thereby include all of both traits.

I'm trying to build an importer class that takes data, does something. I'm using a fluent interface (so lots of `return $this`). I want other third parties to be able to extend it by adding their own methods, but this whole thing is really about the developer experience, and so I'd like IDEs to be able to pickup the methods made available by plugins.

Comment: _":static would be nice, but is invalid, not supported/implemented in PHP."_ `:static` return type was added in PHP 8 and works exactly as you desire.

Comment: Although not helpful, I'm using PhpStorm and `$o->a()->` does offer me both `a() and `b()` as options using your above traits, so I think this is a limitation of the library you are using, and not the language itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that the following works, though am open to alternative answers too.

```php
<?php
class A {
  /**
   * @return static
   */
  public function a() { return $this; }
}

class LocalA {
  /**
   * @return static
   */
  public function b() { return $this; }
}

$o = new LocalA();
$o->➊ // offers a() and b() ✔
$o->a()->➊ // offers a() and b() ✔
$o->a()->b()->➊ // offers a() and b() ✔
```

It seems a shame I can't actually specify this within the PHP language, though.

Comment: More specifically, you can't specify `: static` as return type **until PHP 7.4**; the solution is to remove the return type or, as you did, put methods in the implementation rather than the trait (or use manual composition instead! That is what traits provide). — Alternatively, upgrade to PHP8 to get the new features; it should be the minimum version anyway, given that since November 2022 ended the LTS for PHP 7.4).

Answer (score 1):

There's no construct in *PHP7.4* that would support this.
Support for static return types has been added only from *PHP 8.0*.

You have 4 possible solutions:

- remove the return type, so it doesn't create the issue; but is an hack and doesn't help with developer experience (that was you whole point).
- implement manual composition, put the implementation in `UtilityA::a()` method, then call it from `A::a(): self` or `LocalA::a(): self` so you workaround the issue and specify `self` inside the correct classes.
  This is a more traditional method, given that PHP Traits were added to favour *opp-composition*. So you implement traits using only classes.
  Is more boilerplate tho, although not much more than wiring PHP Trait using the alias syntax: `UtilityA::a as a`.
- simply move the methods in the concrete classes; your answer suggests that. It solves the developer experience, but for the sake of it you are forced to change your design for encapsulation.
- upgrade to PHP 8 and get the benefit of `: static` return type support.